# Anybody know what this type of visualisation is called?

Tags: visualization

I think this is a pretty cool way to visualise changes in values but I can’t find any name for this type of visualisation.

I[image]

Source: https://www.economist.com/graphic-detail/2020/07/28/americans-are-getting-more-nervous-about-what-they-say-in-public

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This type of visualization is called Arrow and Range plot.

You can refer [here](https://academy.datawrapper.de/article/123-how-to-create-an-arrow-plot)